# How arrange this array in ascending order by date?

Tags: php, arrays

this is my array

```
[comment] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [mem_id] => 51
                    [comment] => nice...
                    [profilenam] => xyz
                    [photo_thumb] => photos/81951b37ad01c4aa65662956f178214eth.jpeg
                    [date] => 1307975661
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [mem_id] => 329
                    [comment] => nice...
                    [profilenam] => abc
                    [photo_thumb] => photos/f841eab12f5a24ce12b984904760c05fth.jpeg
                    [date] => 1308043486
                )

        )
```

actually i wanted to arrange in ascending order by date , i used asort() but didn't work

Comment: You're going to need `usort()` for that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Seems like the comments are coming from the DB, why not sure 'ORDER BY date ASC' in the query getting these results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sort multidimensional array by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: @Sabeen: Out of curiosity, what makes you think these are coming from a database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Sort a multidimensional array by element containing date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sort+multidimensional+array+php

Comment: @Sabeen Malik, thanks man i wasted 2-2:30 hrs to arrange this array using many way thanks a lot

Comment: @Evert the hunch is mainly based on the way the array looks like. The ids and the date in the unix timestamp format suggests the same too. So just a suggestion in case that was the case :)

Answer (score 5):

```
usort($ar['comment'], function($v1, $v2) {
    return $v1['date'] - $v2['date'];
});
```

In php<5.3, use [create_function](http://php.net/create_function) instead of the anonymous function notation.

Comment: Instead of the `if`s, you could simply write `return $v1['date'] - $v2['date'];`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting array of array, in this case none of the built-in sort function with built-in comparison function would work. Try [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) or [uasort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but something like this:

```
uasort($comment, function ($a, $b) { return $a['date'] - $b['date']; } );
```