# Sort array of objects by date field

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can I re-arrange a array of objects like this:

```
 [495] => stdClass Object
        (
         [date] => 2009-10-31 18:24:09
         ...
        )
 [582] => stdClass Object
        (
         [date] => 2010-2-11 12:01:42
         ...
        )
 ...
```

by the `date` key, oldest first ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
});
```

Or if you don't have PHP 5.3:

```
function cb($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
}
usort($array, 'cb');
```

Comment: Looks good, and I'd recommend to the OP to do the date/time sorting in the database, and/or return a plain unix timestamp along with the formatted value, as strtotime() has CONSIDERABLE overhead and would make repeated sorting very expensive.

Comment: replace `usort` by `uasort` then

Answer (score 24):

Since the original question is about sorting arrays of stdClass() objects, here's the code which would work if $a and $b are objects:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a->date) - strtotime($b->date);
});
```

Or if you don't have PHP 5.3:

```
function cb($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a->date) - strtotime($b->date);
}
usort($array, 'cb');
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to expand on `arnaud576875`'s answer. I ran across this same issue, but with using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects. This is how I was able to accomplish the same thing.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['date']->format('U') - $b['date']->format('U');
});
```

Comment: Are you calling the `format()` method on a string value? This answer feels misleading to researchers.  The OP's sample data is an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Because your month -- and possibly your day -- values are not zero-padded, you cannot instantly compare the dates as simple strings.  You should use `strtotime()` to convert the dates to unix time integers -- these will be suitable for reliable comparisons.

Also, it seems important to not lose the associative relationship between the first level keys and their objects.  To sort and retain the keys, call `uasort()`. In modern php, the spaceship operator is the go-to utility for making 3-way comparisons (returns -1, 0, or 1).

All approaches below will work identically even if the 2d array is an array of arrays instead of an array of objects (you'll only need to change the `->date` syntax to `['date']`.

Code:

```
uasort(
    $array,
    function($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($a->date) <=> strtotime($b->date);
    }
);
```

Or in PHP7.4, there is arrow function syntax:

```
uasort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) => strtotime($a->date) <=> strtotime($b->date)
);
```

The only minor drawback with using function calls in `u*sort()`'s body is that it will do greater than *n* sets of function calls to break ties and otherwise determine the correct order.  An alternative sorting technique that avoids these redundant function calls is `array_multisort()`. It can be fed a column of data which has had exactly *n* function calls performed -- this effectively makes it more efficient.  However, this sorting function has its own caveat -- it will lose the numeric first level keys.  This is probably not a tolerable loss for this case.

Code:

```
array_multisort(
    array_map('strtotime', array_column($array, 'date')),
    $array
);
```

Here is [a demo of both techniques](https://3v4l.org/AVdJb).

For anyone who is sorting date, time, or datetime values that can be naturally compared as basic strings (so-called [Big-endian](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/what-is-little-endian-and-big-endian/) formats such as `Y-m-d H:i:s`, `H:i`, `m/d`, `Y-m-d`, etc., then see [this answer for more efficient techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67124505/2943403).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to expand on arnaud576875 and Michael Irigoyen.

Same issue with object containing dateTime with Symphony.

I coudn't use $a['date'] because it was not an key array.

```
usort($verifications, function($a, $b) {
   return $a->getDate()->format('U') - $b->getDate()->format('U');
});
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

When working with DateTime objects as properties of your Entity, this worked for me:

```
$myArray = $entityRepository->findAll();

usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->getDate()->getTimestamp() - $b->getDate()->getTimestamp();
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).