# How do I order times and dates from smallest to largest in order to extract data chronologically in PHP?

Tags: php, web-scraping

How can I order times and dates from smallest to largest in order to extract data in a chronological order using PHP (not MySQL)?

I have an array with objects with various "keys" which include the time and the event.

Here is an edited `var_dump` of what I have:

```
[0] => object {
    ["time"] => "24/06/2015 - 12:30 PM"
    ["event"] => "Another event"
}
[1] => object {
    ["time"] => "24/06/2015 - 08:45 AM"
    ["event"] => "Event"
}
[2] => object {
    ["time"] => "25/06/2015 - 09:50 AM"
    ["event"] => "Yet another event"
}
```

I want the output to be something similar to:

> 24/06/2015:
>
> Event
>
> Another event
>
> 25/06/2015:
>
> Yet another event

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by date field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127764/sort-array-of-objects-by-date-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the usort standard php function with the following custom function :

```
function sortbytobjtime($a, $b){
    $adate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y - h:i a', $a->time);
    $bdate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y - h:i a', $b->time);
    if ( $adate == $bdate ) return 0;
    return ( $adate < $bdate) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr, 'sortbytobjtime');
```

$arr being an array filled with objects as described in your question.
Note that this solution needs PHP 5 with version >= 5.3.0 in order to have the DateTime class available.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to rearrange the array so keys are timestamp values:

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($objArr as $obj) {
  $newArr[ strtotime( $obj->time ) ] = $obj;
}
```

Then, you can use [ksort()](https://www.php.net/krsort) or [krsort()](https://www.php.net/ksort).

Comment: strtotime has trouble reading the date I provide. It's in a format it doesn't understand.