# How to sort an array by date field descending order?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have an array like below. I want to sort this array in descending order using date. But my code is not working.

```
$tbData = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Baby Boo
            [1] => 31921
            [2] => 07 Oct, 2016 07:27 pm
        )

   [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Moonshine
            [1] => 32110
            [2] => 07 Oct, 2016 09:12 pm
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hulk
            [1] => 31374
            [2] => 13 Sep, 2016 03:00 pm
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sweet SHAI
            [1] => 667
            [2] => 05 Oct, 2016 09:36 am
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hulk
            [1] => 31374
            [2] => 13 Sep, 2016 03:01 pm
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Maple
            [1] => 2270
            [2] => 08 Oct, 2016 07:31 am
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Josie
            [1] => 
            [2] => 08 Oct, 2016 04:40 pm
        )
)
```

I am trying to solve this question using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16733128) Stack Overflow question. But it's not working for me.

My code is like below:

```
$name = 2;
usort($tbData, function ($a, $b) use (&$name) {
     return strtotime($a[$name]) - strtotime($b[$name]);
});
```

My date column filed is something different. That's why may be my code is not working. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Related: [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2167916/2943403) and [Sort array of objects by date field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67108550/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, the core issue here is that `strtotime` doesn't understand your date time format. You could have figured that out by looking at the return value, which is `FALSE` if conversion fails.

So, the solution is to use another function to do the conversion, eg [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) and extract the epoch second value from that DateTime using [date_timestamp_get](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) to compare those, like this:

```
usort($tbData, function ($a, $b) {
    $sa = date_create_from_format('d M, Y H:i a',$a[2]);
    $sb = date_create_from_format('d M, Y H:i a',$b[2]);
    return date_timestamp_get($sa) - date_timestamp_get($sb);
});
```

Comment: Thanks its working. but its ascending order. I think your return function like this for descending order.  return date_timestamp_get($sb) - date_timestamp_get($sa);