# sort array based on the dateTime in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [dateTime] => 2011-10-18 0:0:00
                    [chanl1] => 20.7
                    [chanl2] => 45.4
                    [chanl3] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [dateTime] => 2011-10-18 0:15:00
                    [chanl1] => 20.7
                    [chanl2] => 45.4
                    [chanl3] => 
                )


            [2] => Array
                (
                    [dateTime] => 2011-10-18 00:14:00
                    [chanl1] => 20.7
                    [chanl2] => 33.8
                    [chanl3] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [dateTime] => 2011-10-18 00:29:00
                    [chanl1] => 20.6
                    [chanl2] => 33.9
                    [chanl3] => 
                )
```

I want to sort the above array based on the [dateTime], the final output should be:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [dateTime] => 2011-10-18 0:0:00
                    [chanl1] => 20.7
                    [chanl2] => 45.4
                    [chanl3] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [dateTime] => 2011-10-18 00:14:00
                    [chanl1] => 20.7
                    [chanl2] => 33.8
                    [chanl3] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [dateTime] => 2011-10-18 0:15:00
                    [chanl1] => 20.7
                    [chanl2] => 45.4
                    [chanl3] => 
                )            

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [dateTime] => 2011-10-18 00:29:00
                    [chanl1] => 20.6
                    [chanl2] => 33.9
                    [chanl3] => 
                )
```

Is there anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: The datetime data in this question is "Big-endian", so there is no need to parse the column values -- just [comparing them as strings is 100% reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67124505/2943403).

Answer (score 65):

Use [`usort()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with custom comparator:

```
$arr = array(...);

usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
  $ad = new DateTime($a['dateTime']);
  $bd = new DateTime($b['dateTime']);

  if ($ad == $bd) {
    return 0;
  }

  return $ad < $bd ? -1 : 1;
});
```

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class has overloaded comparison operators (`<`, `>`, `==`).

Comment: it should be usort(**$arr, **function($a, $b) but the rest is ok

Comment: @Crozin It is a common misconception that usort has to return `-1,0,1`. Like the manual states: *The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.* and that means any value `<=>0`.

Comment: @Gordon: Yeah, I know that fact, however if we're operating on something that is not a number (DateTime in this case) it's a common practice to return `±1`.

Comment: Isn't the ternary backwards? Unless there's something silly that I'm missing, if the first value is less than the second then you should be returning a value <0. I think it should be ```return $ad < $bd ? -1 : 1;```

Comment: @JohnPancoast  Or just return $ad > $bd ? 1 : -1

Comment: @Jaaaaaaay Yea, yours has the same effect as mine but the OPs original was different.

Comment: Note: switch -1 and 1 around to change general order to descending

Comment: I'm glad we can use the spaceship operator `<=>` in PHP 7. :)

Answer (score 22):

For performance, this method using [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) is very [efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707150/using-a-static-class-method-to-quickly-sort-an-array-by-key-value-in-php/17709377#17709377):

```
$ord = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    $ord[] = strtotime($value['dateTime']);
}
array_multisort($ord, SORT_ASC, $array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: I was trying to sort an array of datetime objects and this worked great for me. Thanks! I modified it a bit to just be ````array_multisort($array, SORT_ASC, $array);````

Answer (score 14):

Simple sorting for DateTime objects with the spaceship operator:

```
$list = [
    new DateTime('yesterday'),
    new DateTime('today'),
    new DateTime('1 week ago'),
];

uasort($list, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a <=> $b;
});

var_dump($list);
```

Answer (score 12):

Using [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) with a custom sort callback should do it:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a['dateTime'] == $b['dateTime']) {
    return 0;
  }

  return ($a['dateTime'] < $b['dateTime']) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($arr, 'cmp');
```

`uasort()` preserves your array's keys, you can use [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) instead if you don't need that to happen.

Comment: You shouldn't compare string values with `<` operator.

Comment: @Petah Because you are assuming a specific date format, Crozins answer is much more usable.

Comment: @h.coates yes, you are correct that I am assuming it is in the format that is given in the sample data. Why would it not be?

Answer (score 5):

For php array and object this example is helpful for sorting...

For datetime descending:

```
usort($response_data['callback'], function($a, $b) {
   return strcasecmp(strtotime($b->view_date), strtotime($a->view_date));
});
```

For datetime ascending:

```
usort($response_data['callback'], function($a, $b) {
   return strtotime($a->view_date) - strtotime($b->view_date);
});
```

Comment: I like the subtraction part of your solution. This is pretty neat and (at least for me) better to read than the whole `$a < $b ? -1 : ($a > $b ? 1 : 0)` stuff. … With a current PHP version I'd rather use the spaceship operator `<=>` but in single cases you can't just switch a running project to latest PHP version (as in my current case where the customer has some … "issues" with updating. ;)).

Answer (score 3):

Use array_multisort :

```
 <?php
        $myarray=array(
                    0 => array
                        (
                            'dateTime' => '2011-10-18 00:0:00',
                            'chanl1' => '20.7',
                            'chanl2' => '45.4',
                            'chanl3' => '',
                        ),

                    1 => array
                        (
                            'dateTime' => '2011-10-18 00:15:00',
                            'chanl1' => '20.7',
                            'chanl2' => '45.4',
                            'chanl3' => '',
                        ),
                  2 => array
                        (
                            'dateTime' => '2011-10-18 00:14:00',
                            'chanl1' => '20.7',
                            'chanl2' => '33.8',
                            'chanl3' => '',
                        ),

                    3 => array
                        (
                            'dateTime' => '2011-10-18 00:29:00',
                            'chanl1' => '20.6',
                            'chanl2' => '33.9',
                            'chanl3' => ''
                        ));

            foreach($myarray as $c=>$key) {
                    $dateTime[] = $key['dateTime'];
                $chanl1[] = $key['chanl1'];
                    $chanl2[] = $key['chanl2'];
                    $chanl3[] = $key['chanl3'];
            }

        array_multisort($dateTime,SORT_ASC,SORT_STRING,$myarray);   
        print_r($myarray);
```