# How to sort array by datatime values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [dep] => 23:24
            [seconds] => 84240
            [date] => 2014-05-15 23:24:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [dep] => 04:49
            [seconds] => 17340
            [date] => 2014-05-16 04:49:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [dep] => 04:22
            [seconds] => 15720
            [date] => 2014-05-16 04:22:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [dep] => 04:07
            [seconds] => 14820
            [date] => 2014-05-16 04:07:00
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [dep] => 00:04
            [seconds] => 240
            [date] => 2014-05-16 00:04:00
        )

)
```

I would like sort and get something like:
1. 2014-05-15 23:24:00

1. 2014-05-16 00:04:00
2. 2014-05-16 04:07:00
3. 2014-05-16 04:22:00
4. 2014-05-16 04:49:00

Thanks for replay ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121241/sort-array-based-on-the-datetime-in-php

Answer (score 0):

How about translating the values into unix time and sorting by that?

Comment: //your array with details
$datatimearray;

$tmparray = array()
foreach($datatimearray as $key => $val)
{
 $settime = strtotime($val);
}

ksort($tmparray);

$datatimearray = $tmparray;

print_r($datatimearray);

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably the easiest solution:

```
sort(strtotime($array['date']));
```

Comment: `sort(strtotime($array['date']))` will that work?

Comment: It converts all the dates to timestamps and sorts them. It should work. Of course, you have to adjust the name of the array according to your arrayname.

Comment: had that question since the array is multi-dimensional

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime` on each of those fields and then sort them with `asort`.