# converting and sorting dates in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, date

I am trying to sort a table of dates, yet the problem that I seem to have is that these dates are strings formatted as `d M Y` (so something like `"04 SEPT 2016"`).

I'm assuming that these dates are not stored as timestamps in the database (if that makes sense), but rather as a normal string that needs to be converted back into something that can be sorted.

Comment: you can use like this format: $current_date_time=$date->format( 'Y-m-d G:i:s' );... If you give clear information.. i could help you to solve you..

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use the [datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) interface. See specifics about the format specifier on the manpage. It allows to parse a date into an object by giving format specifiers. The DateTime class supports sorting and operators such as `<`, `>`, `==`, etc.

You can parse a date using:

```
$list = [];
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat($time, 'd M Y');
$list[] = $d;  ### add to list
```

Now you can sort it as `DateTime` supports sorting:

```
sort($list);
reset($list);
foreach($list as $sorted_date) {
  ...
}
```

See also [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121241/sort-array-based-on-the-datetime-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

It does make sense, and how you approach this will depend on what you want to do.

You can convert a string into a date using php's datetime function:
(procedural method)

```
<?php
$date = date_create_from_format('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

---

Or, if you want to select/update/modify/etc within a MySQL database query (slight assumption that you'll be using MySQL), you can use the STR_TO_DATE function

```
STR_TO_DATE('21,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y');
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/

The bigger question here is whether you have scope to convert the dates from strings to dates within the DB, as this is the correct way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(field, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM  table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(field, '%m/%d/%Y')

Answer (score 0):

**If you want sort with PHP then you can try this trick:**

```
<?php
    $myarray=array(
        "2 SEPT 2016",
        "9 SEPT 2016",
        "1 OCT 2016",
        "3 DEC 2016",
        "4 SEPT 2016",
    );
    usort($myarray, "cmpare");
    print_r($myarray);

    function cmpare($x, $y){ 
        return strcmp(strtotime($y), strtotime($x)); 
    }
?>
```