# PHP sort multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How can I sort this first by Member id and then by Payment date?

```
Array
(
    [240] => Array
        (
            [Member] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 112
                )

            [Payment] => Array
                (
                    [date] => 0712


)
    )
```

I tried with multisort, but I never found a way what was working and all examples I found didn't had my additional level.

Comment: look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date

Comment: This question is Unclear and a poor fit for Stack Overflow because it doesn't contain a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Is the date value a string or an integer?

Anyway, supposing that date is an int, you could try this:

```
function my_sort($val1, $val2) {
    $compare_id = $val1['Member']['id'] - $val2['Member']['id'];
    if($compare_id == 0) {
        return $val1['Payment']['date'] - $val2['Payment']['date'];
    }
    else return $compare_id;
}
```

and then call:

```
usort($array, 'my_sort');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is received from database you can use `... ORDER BY member,date`

Comment: And, from the looks of it, you're using CakePHP? You just have to include those in your array (at the same level as 'conditions')