# Is it safe to compare dates with no delimiters in Ymd format?

Tags: php, string, date, compare

Can I compare two dates in a string like numbers? Or should I retype them to ints?

Is this code ok?

```
<?php
$date1 = "20130102";
$date2 = "20151012";

if ($date1 < $date2){
    echo "date1 < date2";
} elseif ($date1 > $date2){
    echo "date1 > date2";
} else {
    echo "date1 = date2";
}
?>
```

Comment: Sure it's safe but it *probably* won't give you the right result - you're just comparing strings - look into `strtotime`.

Comment: Actually, it will give the right result, as long as the dates are in the format as shown.  However agree with `strtotime` but also check the more object oriented `DateTime` class: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: It will give you the right result as long as your values are in yyyymmdd order.

Comment: Topically relevant: [PHP Sort a multidimensional array by element containing Y-m-d H:i:s date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67124505/2943403)  You are dealing with "big endian" strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is safe and correct under the following condition: Iff your dates are formatted like Ymd (according to php's [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

The reason this works is that in all character sets that I can imagine the characters 0-9 sort exactly like the numbers 0-9 do. If you then use leading 0s your strings sort just like numbers.

N.B. that using strings as a data type for dates is a code smell. See [this page](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) (no.7)

Comment: @user1640032 If I were you, I'd validate that fact before you test them.

Comment: @lonesomeday how would you do that in this case: `20130104` and `20130301` ?

Comment: These dates are stored in DB in YYYYMMDD format, so it is already validated.

Comment: To lonesomeday: I hope that it will work for 20130104 and 20130301 if you have these dates in format YYYYMMDD => 20130104 < 20130301.