# PHP Sort Array by date value

Tags: php, arrays, date, sorting

I have the following array format in my php code:

```
foreach ($events as $info) {
    $events_array[] = array(
        'title' => $info->Name,
        'date'  => $info->Date
    );
}
function cb($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['date']) - strtotime($b['date']);
}
usort($events_array, 'cb');
```

Edit: The date values are in the format: YYYY-MM-DD

Actually, when I do print_r, I get

```
[title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [date] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

Comment: please don't use the `foo: .. endfoo;` syntax in files contactual code. that syntax was always meant for templating and most developer will not expect or appreciate it being used anywhere else

Comment: are you sure there was anything in the array to begin with? do the print_r() BEFORE you call usort.

Comment: does events_array have values before the sort?

Comment: Actually, when I do print_r, I get title=> SimpleXMLObject, and date=>SimpleXMLObject

Comment: Maybe that's why it's not echoing any values?

Comment: seems like `$info->Date` doesn't return a string and then the comparison doesn't work either...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to create your own multi column sort function (because your array is 2-dimensional):

```
array_sort_by_column($events_array, 'date');

var_dump($events_array);
```

The sorting function:

```
function array_sort_by_column(&$array, $column, $direction = SORT_ASC) {
    $reference_array = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $row) {
        $reference_array[$key] = $row[$column];
    }

    array_multisort($reference_array, $direction, $array);
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php <-- example #2 uses a 2 dimensional array so our statement that he has to do it different bevause of the 2 dimensionality is wrong...

Comment: ITroubs is right, here is how to do it with usort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date