# How do you modify a UNION query in CakePHP 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to paginate a union query in CakePHP 3.0.0. By using a [custom finder](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-find-methods), I have it working *almost* perfectly, but I can't find any way to get `limit` and `offset` to apply to the union, rather than either of the subqueries.

In other words, this code:

```
$articlesQuery = $articles->find('all');
$commentsQuery = $comments->find('all');
$unionQuery = $articlesQuery->unionAll($commentsQuery);
$unionQuery->limit(7)->offset(7); // nevermind the weirdness of applying this manually
```

produces this query:

```
(SELECT {article stuff} ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 7 OFFSET 7)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT {comment stuff})
```

instead of what I want, which is this:

```
(SELECT {article stuff})
UNION ALL 
(SELECT {comment stuff})
ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 7 OFFSET 7
```

I *could* manually construct the correct query string like this:

```
$unionQuery = $articlesQuery->unionAll($commentsQuery);
$sql = $unionQuery->sql();
$sql = "($sql) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 7 OFFSET 7";
```

but my custom finder method needs to return a `\Cake\Database\Query` object, not a string.

So,

- Is there a way to apply methods like `limit()` to an entire union query?
- If not, is there a way to convert a SQL query string into a Query object?

Note:
There's [a closed issue](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5107) that describes something similar to this (except using `paginate($unionQuery)`) without a suggestion of how to overcome the problem.

### Apply limit and offset to each subquery?

scrowler kindly suggested this option, but I think it won't work. If `limit` is set to 5 and the full result set would be this:

```
Article 9     --|
Article 8       |
Article 7       -- Page One
Article 6       |
Article 5     --|

Article 4     --|
Comment 123     |
Article 3       -- Here be dragons
Comment 122     |
Comment 121   --|
...
```

Then the query for page 1 would work, because (the first five articles) + (the first five comments), sorted manually by date, and trimmed to just the first five of the combined result would result in articles 1-5.

**But page 2 won't work**, because the `offset` of 5 would be applied to both articles and comments, meaning the first 5 comments (which weren't included in page 1), will never show up in the results.

Comment: One option would be to apply the limit and offset to articles and comments separately

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I don't think that will actually produce the intended pagination result. Like if a full result set, ordered by the `created` field, returns 20 new articles before any new comments, then page 1 would be correct, but page 2 would- damn it, I need to just type this out in the answer...

Comment: I see - you'll need to apply the order and limit around the entire union (as in your example) - not sure how to achieve that in Cake. Good luck

Comment: What happens if you do $unionQuery->select()->limit(7)->offset(7) ? I don't know CakePHP ORM but reading the doc I think it may create a subquery with your union...

Comment: In doc of Cake.Database.Query (which is what unionAll return) there is something like this: $query->select(['sub' => $countQuery]); // FROM (SELECT ...) sub

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Being able to apply these clauses *directly* on the query returned by `unionAll()` is not possible AFAIK, it would require changes to the API that would make the compiler aware where to put the SQL, being it via options, a new type of query object, whatever.

### Query::epilog() to the rescue

Luckily it's possible to append SQL to queries using [**`Query::epilog()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_epilog), being it raw SQL fragments

```
$unionQuery->epilog('ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 7 OFFSET 7');
```

or query expressions

```
$unionQuery->epilog(
    $connection->newQuery()->order(['created' => 'DESC'])->limit(7)->offset(7)
);
```

This should give you the desired query.

It should be noted that according to the docs `Query::epilog()` expects either a string, or a concrete `\Cake\Database\ExpressionInterface` implementation in the form a `\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression` instance, not just *any* `ExpressionInterface` implementation, so theoretically the latter example is invalid, even though the query compiler works with any `ExpressionInterface` implementation.

### Use a subquery

It's also possible to utilize the union query as a subquery, this would make things easier in the context of using the pagination component, as you wouldn't have to take care of anything other than building and injecting the subquery, since the paginator component would be able to simply apply the order/limit/offset on the main query.

```
/* @var $connection \Cake\Database\Connection */
$connection = $articles->connection();

$articlesQuery = $connection
    ->newQuery()
    ->select(['*'])
    ->from('articles');
    
$commentsQuery = $connection
    ->newQuery()
    ->select(['*'])
    ->from('comments');
    
$unionQuery = $articlesQuery->unionAll($commentsQuery);

$paginatableQuery = $articles
    ->find()
    ->from([$articles->alias() => $unionQuery]);
```

This could of course also be moved into a finder.

Comment: Brilliant! `Query::epilog()` wasn't in the docs, and I had overlooked it when I was perusing the class file. Thanks!

Comment: Caveat: It appears that the pagination component can't find the total number of records if limit is applied through `epilog()`. Or rather, it assumes that the total number of records is equal to the limit. This is due to how `count()` works: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records

Comment: @PhantomWatson You should be able to workaround this by using a custom counter (see `Query::counter()`), can't test it right now, but theoretically obtaining a copy of the query and unsetting the epilog should do it, from there on it should be safe to invoke `Query::count()` on the query copy. I'll test it later on and update my answer.

Comment: I was too quick to despair. Using `$unionQuery->counter(...)` at the end of the custom finder method, even after using `epilog()`, works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @ndm Is this changed in the last release? `$unionQuery->epilog('LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0');` put limit and offset to both queries in the union, when I use pagination.

Comment: @rrd As far as I can tell the behavior is still the same. It only works with custom finders though.

Comment: @ndm hm. I have a custom finder, custom counter added, but still I getting wrong sql. Any idea how can I find out why?

Comment: @rrd As always, debugging, debugging, debugging, and even more debugging :) Add breakpoints, from your custom finder up to the paginator component, check where exactly the query is being changed. You may want to open a separate question where you can show some code. All I can do from here is guessing.

Comment: This is really old, but @PhantomWatson you might be interested in the subquery example that I just added...

Comment: ...and @rrd might find it interesting too.

Comment: @ndm this post should be added to the cakephp documentation. its highly valuable

Comment: @alexdd55 You may want to create an issue over at **https://github.com/cakephp/docs** and reference this.