# Is there anyway to sort data after union two queries?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

```
$query = $queryOne->unionAll($queryTwo)->order(['Headers.id' => 'desc']);
```

this is not working.

Comment: By the way.I can get the results , but order not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try making View in Mysql to sort after UNION.

Otherwise there is no way to do that in Cake structure.

Comment: ok, I will create a view for it. thank you!

Comment: That's not correct, the CakePHP query builder comes with functionality to append SQL via the `epilog()` method. **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379579/how-do-you-modify-a-union-query-in-cakephp-3/29386189#29386189**. Also one could always utilize subqueries.

Comment: But by this way can we use pagination in that?

Comment: Yes, you can. However unless you're using a subquery solution, using the paginator component will require to use a finder where you manually apply the order/limit/offset on the union query. Also you'd have to use a custom counter in order to count on the union query without the limiting epilog SQL applied.

Comment: I've updated my answer to the linked question with a subquery example...