# How to reference columns to order a union query?

Tags: cakephp, sql-order-by, union, query-builder

I have done a Union in cakephp 3, however the union is doing it such that the buyers table records are shown first and then the tenants.  Whereas i want it to be arranged based on created field in both Buyers and Tenants table so the latest records appears first.  I tried doing that using epilog but gives an error

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created' in 'order clause'

```
$tenant = $this->Tenants
    ->find('all', [
        'fields' => ['Tenants.id', 'Tenants.created', 'Consumers.type'],
        'conditions' => ['Tenants.client_id' => '1'],
        'order' => 'Tenants.created desc'
    ])
    ->contain(['Consumers']);

$buyer = $this->Buyers
    ->find('all', [
        'fields' => ['Buyers.id', 'Buyers.created', 'Consumers.type'],
        'conditions' => ['Buyers.client_id' => '1'],
        'order' => 'Buyers.created desc'
    ])
    ->contain(['Consumers']);

$results = $buyer->unionAll($tenant);
$results->epilog('ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 7 OFFSET 7');
```

Comment: what is the relation between these 2 tables

Answer (score 0):

The high level ORM query builder will select columns using aliases, ie it will create `SELECT` clauses like this:

```
SELECT Tenants.id AS Tenants__id, Tenants.created AS Tenants__created, etc...
```

So your epilog snippet won't see a `created` column, hence the error. In such a case the most simple thing is to reference the column via its position number (though in at least MySQL that's deprecated IIRC!):

```
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Alternatively select the `created` column additionally with a common alias, like:

```
['Tenants.id', 'Tenants.created', 'created' => 'Tenants.created', 'Consumers.type']
['Buyers.id', 'Buyers.created', 'created' => 'Buyers.created', 'Consumers.type']
```

that will select the column like `Tenants.created AS created`, and you can reference it in your `ORDER BY` clause via `created`.

At least in MySQL it also seems to work to reference one of the aliases if the two queries are using different aliases for the same column (as union selects work on a position basis), but I'm not sure if this is true for other DBMS', anyways for the sake of completion, the following could work too:

```
ORDER BY Tenants__created DESC
```

Comment: Pagination not working 

$results = $buyer->unionAll($tenant);
$results->epilog('ORDER BY created DESC');

Comment: @UsmanSaeed That's a different problem, see for example **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379579/how-do-you-modify-a-union-query-in-cakephp-3/29386189#29386189**, you'd have to use the union in a subquery.

Comment: Ok thanks, any idea what the code will be for that please?

Comment: @UsmanSaeed Please check the linked answer, it contains an example.

Comment: Tried but no luck with it

Comment: @UsmanSaeed I'm sorry but I can't really help with "_doesn't work_". If there's a specific problem with that new task, then I'd suggest that you create a new question, where you can explain the problem in detail and show your attempts / your code.

Comment: Added a new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291582/pagination-not-working-in-a-cakephp-3-union