# PHP slice associative array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array

```
$array = array(
    "13111" => "2014-06-21 19:51:00.0000000",
    "23111" => "2014-06-20 19:51:00.0000000",
    "12111" => "2014-06-21 19:51:00.0000000",
    "23311" => "2014-06-22 19:51:00.0000000",
    "13114" => "2014-06-21 19:51:00.0000000",
    "23711" => "2014-06-20 19:51:00.0000000",
);
```

How can i get first 3 elements of my array and how can i sort by datetime? thanks

Comment: Start from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: Since you haven't made an effort to solve the problem yourself, it seems that you are looking to [hire a paid freelancer to fix the problem for you](http://www.freelancer.com).

Comment: you answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date

Comment: you answer is here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you want is:

```
sort($array);
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 3);
```

first, the [`sort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function will sort them lexicographically (which in this case coincides with the date) and then you [`slice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) it to get the elements you want.

**EDIT**

If you want to preserve the keys just use

```
asort($array); // "asort" instead of simple "sort"
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 3, true); // note the final "true" parameter!
```

Comment: will it be sort by time? and i used  array_slice($array, 0, 3);  as well but when i printed my list my keys were replaced with 0,1,2

Comment: @user3754680 [Read. The. Manual](http://us2.php.net//manual/en/function.array-slice.php). The last parameter.