# Sort array elements by date and time in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This question is already asked on this website.
[QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date)

But, I am using codeigniter. And I don't know how to use callback function in that.

My array looks like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 61
        [date_added] => 2014-06-19 16:40:55
        [local_branch_revenue] => 2.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 51
        [date_added] => 2014-06-19 16:23:17
        [local_branch_revenue] => 2.00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 41
        [date_added] => 2014-06-19 14:57:56
        [local_branch_revenue] => 2.00
    )
)
```

And I my controller:

```
usort($info['final_array'], 'date_compare');
```

Within that controller:

```
function date_compare($a, $b){
    $t1 = strtotime($a['date_added']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['date_added']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}
```

ERROR:

```
usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback,
function 'date_compare' not found or invalid function name
```

Comment: It isn't any different in CodeIgniter

Comment: check my error. I think it's the problem of function calling..

Comment: See this question for array sorting help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php