# How to sort by primary date key and secondary alphanumeric in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, sorting, date

So I have a 2D array that looks a bit like this:

```
[0] => Array(
    [date] => 23-01-2017
    [name] => bbb
    [othertext] => text2
)
[1] => Array(
    [date] => 23-01-2017
    [name] => aaa
    [othertext] => text3
)
[2] => Array(
    [date] => 24-01-2017
    [name] => aaa
    [othertext] => text1
)
```

**NOTE:** This question is not tagged as MySQL, the database used is MongoDB with the sort type of `'date' => 'asc'`.

Currently this is returned from my database sorted by date, but does not take into account the name property. I'd like to now sort this by `date`, and for entries with the same date to then sort by `name`.

My current approach is to run an `array_multisort` on the data:

```
array_multisort(
    $array['date'], SORT_STRING,
    $array['name'], SORT_STRING,
    $arrayCopy //<--This copy of the array has the full datetime object
);
```

But this then sorts the date as a string, so in certain scenarios it sorts it incorrectly; e.g. `1st March` would go before the `2nd Feb`. If putting the month first then again it sorts incorrectly when Dec/Jan dates are sorted.

What's the correct approach to this? I've seen mention of `usort()`, but I'm unsure how to implement it in this use case. Does `array_multisort` have functionality for dates?

Comment: Simply, add this sort in your sql query `ORDER BY date ASC, name ASC`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date

Comment: My bad :( Well it's the same principe, just add the second param in your sorting query and you are good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>In your database query:</s>

```
SELECT * from `your_table_name` order by date asc, name asc;
```

Maybe this in mongodb:

```
 $cursor->sort(array('date' => 1, 'name' => 1));
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.sort.php

No need to do it in php afterwards.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest doing this via the database.

But if you must use usort or are trying to understand how it works:

```
$arr = [
    [
        'date' => '23-01-2017',
        'name' => 'bbb',
    ],
    [
        'date' => '23-01-2017',
        'name' => 'aaa',
    ],
    [
        'date' => '24-01-2017',
        'name' => 'aaa',
    ],
];

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $aDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $a['date']);
    $bDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $b['date']);


    if ($aDate == $bDate) {
        if ($a['name'] == $b['name']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($aDate < $bDate) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr, "cmp");

print_r($arr);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Outputs:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 23-01-2017
        [name] => aaa
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 23-01-2017
        [name] => bbb
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 24-01-2017
        [name] => aaa
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

With usort-function you could do:

```
$foo = array(
  0 => array(
    "date" => "23-01-2017",
    "name" => "bbb",
    "othertext" => "text2"
  ),
  1 => array(
    "date" => "23-01-2017",
    "name" => "aaa",
    "othertext" => "text3"
  ),
  2 => array(
    "date" => "24-01-2017",
    "name" => "aaa",
    "othertext" => "text1"
  )
);

usort($foo, function($a, $b)
{
  return $a["date"] === $b["date"] ? strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]) : strcmp(strtotime($a["date"]), strtotime($b["date"]));
});

var_dump($foo);
```