# Laravel how to sort multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'd like to sort 4 arrays that are enclosed within 1 array, but I have no clue how to do it.

```
    $poster = [];
    $character = [];
    $title = [];
    $date = [];

    foreach($person->getMovieCredits()->getCast() as $movie)
    {
        array_push($poster, $movie->getPosterPath());
        array_push($character, $movie->getCharacter());
        array_push($title, $movie->getTitle());
        array_push($date, $movie->getReleaseDate()->format('Y'));
    }

    $personArray = [
        'date' => $date,
        'title' => $title,
        'character' => $character,
        'poster' => $poster
    ];
```

The thing is that I would like to sort them by date, but not losing data integrity with other arrays.

How should I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date

Comment: Try `ksort` read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Comment: `array_multisort($date, $poster, $character, $title);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$date = ['2014-04-03', '2013-04-03', '2015-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2013-09-03'];
$title = ['title1', 'title2', 'title4', 'title5', 'title6'];
$character = ['character2', 'character5', 'character1', 'character8', 'character0'];
$poster = ['poster4', 'poster1', 'poster7', 'poster9', 'poster0'];

$personArray = [
    'date' => $date,
    'title' => $title,
    'character' => $character,
    'poster' => $poster
];

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r( $personArray);*/

$length_count = count($date);

$new_array = array();
for($i=0; $i<$length_count ; $i++){
$new_array[$i] = array();
    foreach($personArray as $key => $value){
        $new_array[$i][$key] = $personArray[$key][$i];
    }
}

function date_compare($a, $b){
    $t1 = strtotime($a['date']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['date']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($new_array, 'date_compare');

//print_r( $new_array);
$sorted_array = array();
$sorted_array['date'] = array();
$sorted_array['title'] = array();
$sorted_array['character'] = array();
$sorted_array['poster'] = array();
foreach($new_array as $data){
     array_push($sorted_array['date'], $data['date']);
     array_push($sorted_array['title'], $data['title']);
     array_push($sorted_array['character'], $data['character']);
     array_push($sorted_array['poster'], $data['poster']);
}
//print_r( $sorted_array);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also play around with the Laravel helpers `array_sort()` and `array_sort_recursive()`. Inside the Closure you put a check if the element in the parent array [also is an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) and also sort the inner array.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for help, I managed to do that quite simply:

```
$movieArray = [];
    foreach($person->getMovieCredits()->getCast() as $movie)
    {
        array_push($movieArray, ['date' => $movie->getReleaseDate()->format('Y'), 'poster' => $movie->getPosterPath(),
            'character' => $movie->getCharacter(), 'title' => $movie->getTitle()]);
    }

    asort($movieArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, this multidimensional array:

```
$array = [];
$array[] = [
  'name' => 'Dupont', 'age' => 72,
  'name' => 'Albert', 'age' => 11,
  'name' => 'Durand', 'age' => 56,
  'name' => 'Michel', 'age' => 52
];
```

For sort by age, for example:

```
$columns = array_column($array, 'age');
array_multisort($columns, SORT_ASC, $array);

dump($array);
```

If need sort by 2 columns:

```
$columns_1 = array_column($array, 'name');
$columns_2 = array_column($array, 'age');
array_multisort($columns_1, SORT_ASC, $columns_2, SORT_DESC, $array);

dump($array);
```