# sorting a config variable based on date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, multidimensional-array, laravel-blade

I have a config variable that uses a foreach loop to print out all the objects.  Is there a way to sort what prints out based on date?
Here is my code for printing out the object.  I want to sort it based on `$press['date']`

```
@foreach (config('constants.pressMetadata') as $press)
    <div>
        <p id="quote">{{ $press['title'] }}</p>
        <div class="more label"><a id="link" href="{{$press['url']}}">-{{$press['company']}}: {{$press['date']}}</a></div>
        <hr>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Here is `constants.pressMetadata`:

```
'pressMetadata'=>[
      "AARP" => [
          "id" => 1,
          "company" => "AARP",
          "title" => "Updating Your Résumé for the Digital Age",
          "url" => "http://www.aarp.org/work/job-hunting/info-2016/give-resume-a-digital-reboot.html",
          "date" => "Sep 9, 2016"
      ],
      "Business Insider" => [
          "id" => 2,
          "company" => "Business Insider",
          "title" => "8 things you should always include on your résumé",
          "url" => "http://www.businessinsider.com/what-to-always-include-on-your-resume-2016-1",
          "date" => "Jan 28, 2016"
      ],
      "Morning Journal" => [
          "id" => 3,
          "company" => "Morning Journal",
          "title" => "5 things you missed: Google updates search, Jobscan and more",
          "url" => "http://www.morningjournal.com/article/MJ/20140124/NEWS/140129366",
          "date" => "Jan 24, 2014"
      ],
],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Sort a multidimensional array by element containing date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date)

Comment: you devalue SO as a resource when you do not search existing answer before posting a question.  Look at how many answers would have helped you: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+sort+multidimensional+array+by+date

Comment: downvoted because didn't show any effort to research and self-solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Laravel's collections to make this pretty easy. Wrap the call to `config()` in a call to `collect()`, and then use the `sortBy()` method on the collection to sort the records by the `strtotime()` value of the 'date' key. Use the `sortByDesc()` method if you want to sort the other way.

```
@foreach (collect(config('constants.pressMetadata'))->sortBy(function ($press) { return strtotime($press['date']); }) as $press)
```

[Documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortby).

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was a laravel way of doing this, I just could not find any documentation that did not point me to vanilla php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `usort` function of PHP.

The following code is taken from the PHP manual and changed to reflect your needs

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if (strtotime($a['date']) == strtotime($b['date'])) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strtotime($a['date']) < strtotime($b['date'])) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort(config('constants.pressMetadata'), "cmp");
```

Comment: If you are only going to copy-paste manual code, just leave a link as a comment.  Otherwise please edit your answer to suit this exact question.  This is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: This code does not deliver the expected result.  You did not test before posting.  Do the work if you are going to provide an answer.  Otherwise, delete your answer and move on.

Comment: @mickmackusa here is your tested and fully running script!

Comment: Well done, next time do the right thing without being told.

Comment: @Aaron This code seems to be the correct answer (probably unbeatable).  If this satisfies you, please award the green tick so that your question is deemed resolved.