# Codeigniter sort by date array

Tags: php, sorting, date, codeigniter

i merge my array then i want to sort them by date but my loans and colls have different names in date

heres my code for the merging

```
 $loan = $this->db->get('loans')->result_array();
 $coll = $this->db->get('collectables')->result_array();       
 $result = array_merge($loan, $coll);
```

and heres the output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [loan_id] => 175
        [loan_fullname] => Albano, Zester Quinn
        [loan_amount] => 15000
        [loan_interest] => 2
        [loan_date] => 2017-05-30
        [loan_total_amount] => 15300
        [loan_collectables] => 1
        [loan_user_id] => 30
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [loan_id] => 176
        [loan_fullname] => Amamio, Alyanna
        [loan_amount] => 15000
        [loan_interest] => 2
        [loan_date] => 2017-05-31
        [loan_total_amount] => 15300
        [loan_collectables] => 2
        [loan_user_id] => 32
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [coll_id] => 92
        [coll_date] => 2017-05-30
        [coll_amount] => 15300
        [coll_loan_id] => 175
        [coll_user_id] => 30
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [coll_id] => 93
        [coll_date] => 2017-05-28
        [coll_amount] => 7650
        [coll_loan_id] => 176
        [coll_user_id] => 32
    )

 [4] => Array
    (
        [coll_id] => 94
        [coll_date] => 2017-06-21
        [coll_amount] => 7650
        [coll_loan_id] => 176
        [coll_user_id] => 32
    )
)
```

but i want to sort them by date.. any ideas?? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date)

Comment: you have to use JOIN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello yes you cant sort the arrays by date you need to use the function asort(if you want to do ascending sort), user arsort(if you want to do decending sort). here is the example that will make you understand.

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"2017-05-30", "Ben"=>"2017-01-31", "Joe"=>"2017-05-30");
asort($age);
foreach($age as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}
```