# PHP - While and wrap div

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I need wrap date and all events in one day to div "obal_date" but this not work. The number of events may be different, but I need wrap date + all events. Please how can I do that. Thank you very much.

```
<?php

# This will hold what group we're in
$current_header = '';

# The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();

    $temp_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'datum_eventu', true );

    echo '<div class="obal_over">'; 

    if ( $temp_date != $current_header ) {
        $current_header = $temp_date;
    /*****************output date******************/
    ?>

        <div class="obal_date">

        <?php
            echo "<span class='date'>".date("d", strtotime($current_header))."</span>";
            echo "<span class='month'>".date("M", strtotime($current_header))."</span>";
        ?>

        </div>     
    <?php
    /*****************date end******************/
    }
    /*****************All event action1, action2....******************/
    $title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'nazev_eventu', true );
    $cas = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cas_eventu', true );

    echo '<div class="obal_single">';   
        echo "<span class='cas'>".$cas."</span>";
        echo "<span class='title'>".$title."</span>";
    echo '</div>';  
    echo '</div>';  
    /*****************End event action1, action2....******************/
endwhile;

?>
```

**EDIT1:**

I need get:

> div -> date -> action1 -> action2 -> /div

```
<div class="obal_over">
  <div class="obal_date">
  01Sep
  </div>
  <div class="obal_single">City1 title</div>
  <div class="obal_single">City1 title2</div>
  <div class="obal_single">City3 title</div>
</div>
//..... other date and action again start class="obal_over"
```

But I get

> div -> date -> action -> /div -> div -> action2 -> /div

```
<div class="obal_over">
  <div class="obal_date">
  01Sep
  </div>
  <div class="obal_single">City1 title</div>
</div>   
<div class="obal_over"> 
  <div class="obal_single">City1 title2</div>
</div>
<div class="obal_over"> 
  <div class="obal_single">City3 title</div>
</div>
```

[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004801/php-foreach-and-compare-date)

Comment: `but this not work` - how exactly doesn't work?

Comment: This code create     

`<div class="obal_over">   
    <div class="obal_date">
        <span class="date">01</span><span class="month">Sep</span>
    </div>
    <div class="obal_single">
        <span class="mesto">City 1</span>
        <span class="cas">00:00:00</span>
        <span class="title">Event 1</span>
    </div>
    </div>`
And start again obal_over but I need all action in obal_over

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas I add Edit1 please look. Thank you :)

Comment: Which part is considered **date** and which part is considered **action** (and **action2**)?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas I added it to code now.

Comment: There seems to be no errors from what you have provided. At least I can't see. :|

Comment: I get the right result but I need wrap it all to one div.

Comment: Print the `echo <div class="obal_over"> ..... </div>` tag outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To facilitate the way you want to list dates and city titles, I added a div tag outside the while loop. Then started div with obal_over class (along with  end div tag) in the if condition where you check whether the dates are same or different. Also added end div tag outside while loop to provide proper open and closed div tags.  I think this would work. I can't test...

```
    <?php

# This will hold what group we're in
$current_header = '';
echo '<div>';
# The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();       

    $temp_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'datum_eventu', true );        

    if ( $temp_date != $current_header ) {
        $current_header = $temp_date;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="obal_over">'; 
    /*****************output date******************/
    ?>
        <div class="obal_date">

        <?php
            echo "<span class='date'>".date("d", strtotime($current_header))."</span>";
            echo "<span class='month'>".date("M", strtotime($current_header))."</span>";
        ?>

        </div>     
    <?php
    /*****************date end******************/
    }
    /*****************All event action1, action2....******************/
    $title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'nazev_eventu', true );
    $cas = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cas_eventu', true );

    echo '<div class="obal_single">';   
        echo "<span class='cas'>".$cas."</span>";
        echo "<span class='title'>".$title."</span>";
    echo '</div>';  

    /*****************End event action1, action2....******************/



endwhile;
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, I am getting in result only 01Jan. When I change in `for` current_header to current_headers it is works good, but now I am getting only one div `<div class="obal_over">` for all event and date :(

Comment: I get `<div class="obal_over">all data</div`> not separate <obal over> -> obal_date ->obal_single -> </obal over> again <obal over> ... .Please can you solve this ? :) Thank you !

Comment: I made little changes to your code .. please check.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you very much you  ! :) Have a great day. Now I'm happy :D. I have something similar but my mistake was `echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="obal_over">'; ` . Thank you one more :)