# arrange month name as per order php multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array, first is month array second is result array,

$monthArray = array("Jan 2018,Feb 2018","Mar 2018");

Need to sort the following array in the order of months

```
$result =
array(
        array(
            "day" => "Feb 2018",
            "value" => "101"
        ),
        array(
           "day" => "Jan 2018",
            "value" => "18"
        ),
        array(
           "day" => "Mar 2018",
            "value" => "0"
        )
```

I have to sort result array in month order like below output,

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [day] => Jan 2018
        [value] => 18
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [day] => Feb 2018
        [value] => 101
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [day] => Mar 2018
        [value] => 0
    )
)
```

I am trying by using sort,usort,ksort php functions but its not working.

Comment: Do you mean `$monthArray = array("Jan 2018","Feb 2018","Mar 2018");
`?

Comment: yes,I am trying to sort by this static month array.

Comment: @vrock can this month array be in a non-chronological order. I am assuming it can as there'd be no reason to have this array if not.

Comment: @vrock I would like to echo DavidBarker's concern.  Please confirm that  the sorting array of month-years will **always** or **not always** be in ASC order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$result =
    [
    [
        "day"   => "Feb 2018",
        "value" => "101",
    ],
    [
        "day"   => "Jan 2018",
        "value" => "18",
    ],
    [
        "day"   => "Mar 2018",
        "value" => "0",
    ],
];
usort($result, function($a, $b) {
  return new DateTime($a['day']) <=> new DateTime($b['day']);
});
```

[usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) — Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aa09e901341736b011e6249d974ecb6d8d25a4e4).

Ref [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date).

Comment: This would work to sort by the value of the `day` key in the result array. It would not order the results by the order defined in the month array if it is not in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort chronologically, you don't need your `$monthArray` variable. You can use `strtotime()` to generate a timestamp from the month-year values and sort on these timestamps ascending.  You can compare the values in the sort call by using the spaceship operator (`<=>`) or if your php version is older, you can use subtraction.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hQFTg))

```
$result =[
    ["day" => "Feb 2018", "value" => "101"],
    ["day" => "Jan 2018", "value" => "18"],
    ["day" => "Mar 2018", "value" => "0"]
];

usort($result,function($a,$b){return strtotime($a['day'])-strtotime($b['day']);});

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'day' => 'Jan 2018',
    'value' => '18',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'day' => 'Feb 2018',
    'value' => '101',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'day' => 'Mar 2018',
    'value' => '0',
  ),
)
```

---

If your sorting month-year variable can contain non-chronological ordering, then you *can* use `array_replace()`.

1. Flip `$monthArray` so that the values become keys.
2. Call `array_column()` with a `null` 2nd parameter so that the array is assigned keys using the column data dictated by the 3rd parameter.
3. Replace `$monthArray` values based on associative keys.
4. Reindex the array with `array_values()`.

Different Code, Same Result:

```
$monthArray = ["Jan 2018","Feb 2018","Mar 2018"];

$result =[
    ["day" => "Feb 2018", "value" => "101"],
    ["day" => "Jan 2018", "value" => "18"],
    ["day" => "Mar 2018", "value" => "0"]
];

$result = array_values(array_replace(array_flip($monthArray),array_column($result,null,'day')));
var_export($result);
```

Depending on the size of your input data, this may or may not be faster than `usort()` with two `array_search()` calls on each iteration.  Either way the speed difference will be unnoticeable to your end users.