# Get max value in php from multiple json data

Tags: php

Currently I have this `json data`

**1st Data**

```
{
    "id": 41,
    "userId": 9,
    "description": null,
    "updated_by": "Juan Dela Cruz",
    "created_at": "2019-09-18 10:07:34",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-18 10:07:34"
}
```

**2nd Data**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 9,
    "description": null,
    "updated_by": null,
    "created_at": "2019-09-16 12:46:56",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-16 12:46:56"
}
```

I have this variable `$myData` if you try to echo this `$myData` the above json will be the expected output.

Is it possible to get the most recent `created_at` using this `max()` function of php?

My expected output would be

**1st Data**

```
{
    "id": 41,
    "userId": 9,
    "description": null,
    "updated_by": "Juan Dela Cruz",
    "created_at": "2019-09-18 10:07:34",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-18 10:07:34"
}
```

Since the `created_at` is recently created than to the 2nd data.

Comment: if is it possible you can just do order by from db if you are fetching it from your own local db

Comment: Unfortunately can't do that in my situation.. Of course in my db I can simply query something like this `ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1` but in my php query I can't simply do this.

Comment: If you know how to decode the data - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910611/php-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-element-containing-date gives all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER  BY created_at DESC LIMIT  1,1;`
OR
`SELECT * FROM tbl  ORDER  BY created_at DESC LIMIT  1,1;`

Answer (score 0):

Make one array of two  json data and keep key as after converting `created_at` using `strtotime()`. Then use `max()` in all `array_keys()` and print the array.

```
$a = '{"id":41,"userId":9,"description":null,"updated_by":"Juan Dela Cruz","created_at":"2019-09-18 10:07:34","updated_at":"2019-09-18 10:07:34"}';
$b = '{"id":2,"userId":9,"description":null,"updated_by":null,"created_at":"2019-09-16 12:46:56","updated_at":"2019-09-16 12:46:56"}';
$arr1 = json_decode($a, true);
$key1 = strtotime($arr1['created_at']);
$arr[$key1] = $arr1;
$arr2 = json_decode($b, true);
$key2 = strtotime($arr2['created_at']);
$arr[$key2] = $arr2;
//print_r($arr);
$key = max(array_keys($arr));
print_r($arr[$key]);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/dST92)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve it using usort function.

```
<?php
// $json = "{"id":41,"userId":9,"description":null,"updated_by":"Juan Dela Cruz","created_at":"2019-09-18 10:07:34","updated_at":"2019-09-18 10:07:34"}";
$arr[] = array('id' => 41, "userId" => 9,"created_at" => "2019-09-18 10:07:34");
$arr[] = array('id' => 42, "userId" => 10,"created_at" => "2019-09-16 12:46:56");
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
  $ad = new DateTime($a['created_at']);
  $bd = new DateTime($b['created_at']);

  if ($ad == $bd) {
    return 0;
  }

  return $ad < $bd ? -1 : 1;
});
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```

?>

I am supposing that my $arr is it in this format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41
            [userId] => 9
            [created_at] => 2019-09-18 10:07:34
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 42
            [userId] => 10
            [created_at] => 2019-09-16 12:46:56
        )

)
```

After Sorting, your array will be like this:

```
Array
(

        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 42
                [userId] => 10
                [created_at] => 2019-09-16 12:46:56
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 41
                [userId] => 9
                [created_at] => 2019-09-18 10:07:34
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json = '{
"0":{
    "id": 41,
    "userId": 9,
    "description": null,
    "updated_by": "Juan Dela Cruz",
    "created_at": "2019-09-18 10:07:34",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-18 10:07:34"
},
"1":{
    "id": 2,
    "userId": 9,
    "description": null,
    "updated_by": null,
    "created_at": "2019-09-16 12:46:56",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-16 12:46:56"
}

}';
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($json, true);

function array_sort_by_column(&$arr, $col, $dir = SORT_DESC) {
    $sort_col = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key=> $row) {
        $sort_col[$key] = $row[$col];
    }

    array_multisort($sort_col, $dir, $arr);
}


array_sort_by_column($jsonDecoded, 'created_at');

print_r($jsonDecoded);
?>
```

**Output Will be:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41
            [userId] => 9
            [description] => 
            [updated_by] => Juan Dela Cruz
            [created_at] => 2019-09-18 10:07:34
            [updated_at] => 2019-09-18 10:07:34
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [userId] => 9
            [description] => 
            [updated_by] => 
            [created_at] => 2019-09-16 12:46:56
            [updated_at] => 2019-09-16 12:46:56
        )

)
```

> If you want to change the sorting order then change the parameter
>   `$dir` to `$dir = SORT_ASC`, that is : `function array_sort_by_column(&$arr, $col, $dir = SORT_ASC)`

Then, To get the recent `created_at` from the array you can add the following code (If the sort order is `SORT_DESC` then use `min()` else use `max()` ):

```
print_r($jsonDecoded[min(array_keys($jsonDecoded))]);
```